# How to save two images in azure blob by html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, microsoft.aspnetcore.odata

I'm trying to save two images in the azure blob, but I can only save one.
follow my example:

In the example I have two fields with an image, the idea is to select an image for each card
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji1bW.png)

But my control is prepared to save only one image, how can I add only two images?

my blob flow:

inside the service folder I have a folder called blob that contains 3 classes ( blob, FileUpload, IBlob )
[Image of the blob structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Cvj.png)

**Class Blob:**

```
namespace Services.Blob
{
  public class Blob
  {
    private static string _connectionAzure = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=*******";

    /// <summary>
    /// Uploads de arquivos / blob assíncronos.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Método que vai efetuar o upload da foto da pessoa no Blob Storage.</returns>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<string> UploadBlobFileAsync(IFormFile file)
    {
        // Recupera a connection string da variável de ambiente que definimos no appsettings.
        var contaStorage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionAzure);
        string empresa = "tijoforte";

        //Variável que representa o endpoint do blob storage account.
        var endPointBlob = contaStorage.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        //Tenta recuperar o container em que será salvo o blob, se não existir ele cria.
        // Regras: O nome do container não deve conter letras maíuscúlas.
        var container = endPointBlob.GetContainerReference(empresa); // Nota que aqui vamos passar o nome de cada empresa para criar o contatiner no azure.
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        //Recupera a referência do endereço do blob e faz o upload do mesmo.
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }

        return blockBlob.Uri.ToString();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Salva o nome, e-mail e documento específico.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Método que salva os dados cadastrados nas tabelas do Storage do Azure</return>
    /// <param name="nome">Nome</param>
    /// <param name="email">E-mail</param>
    /// <param name="documentoUrl">Documento.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task Salvar(string id, string nome, string documentoUrl, string tabela)
    {
        //Recupera a connection strung da variável de ambiente que definimos no appsettings
        var contaStorage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionAzure);

        //Cria o client para a tabela.
        var tableClient = contaStorage.CreateCloudTableClient();

        //Tenta recuperar objeto que representará a tabela, se não existir ela cria.
        //O nome da tabela não deve conter letras maíuscúlas.
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tabela.ToLower());
        await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        //Cria o objeto da entidade.
        var retorno = new BlobStorage(id, nome);
        retorno.FotoBlob = documentoUrl;

        //Efetua a inserção da tabela no azure do CDevs.
        var tableOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(retorno);
        await table.ExecuteAsync(tableOperation);
    }
  }
}
```

**Class FileUpload:**

```
namespace Services.Blob
{
   public class FileUpload
   {
    public string UploadBase64Image(string base64Image, string container)
    {
        // Gerra um nome randomico para a imagem.
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";

        // Limpa o has enviado
        var data = new Regex(@"^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,").Replace(base64Image, "");

        // Gera um array de bytes
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

        // Define o blob no qual a imagem será armazenada.
        var blobClient = new BlobClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=****", container, fileName);
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            blobClient.Upload(stream);
        }

        // retorna a url do blob
        return blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }
 }
}
```

**Interface IBlob**

```
namespace Services.Blob
{
   public interface IBlob
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Criação do métodos de uploads, salvar e listar.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IBlob
    {
        Task<string> UploadBlobFileAsync(IFormFile file);
        Task Salvar(string nome, string email, string documentoUrl);
        Task<List<BlobStorage>> Lista();
    }
  }
}
```

After this process, the blob is ready to use.
But it doesn't work if I want it for just two images

Controller WEB:
[Web application structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAqJe.png)

**Controller:**

```
   try
        {
                // tratamento para salvar no blob
                if (file != null)
                {
                        //THE PROBLEM IS HERE ONLY SAVES ONE IMAGE
                        var urlBlob = await Blob.UploadBlobFileAsync(file);
                        await Blob.Salvar(blog.BlogId.ToString(), blog.Nome, urlBlob, nameof(Blog).ToLower());
                        blog.ImagemPequena = urlBlob;
                   
                }

                // Realiza processo de alteração
                var retorno = await Blog().Alterar(blogId, blog);

                return RedirectToAction("Formulario", new { mensagem = $"Registro alterado com sucesso! {blog.Nome}" });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

**

> WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

**

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement  you can find the sample code here in this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/billyctech/AzureBlobLearning) , which saves four files together in blob storage , Instead of that you can use two images to be saved in your blob storage as well.

***OUTPUT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- ***SO THREAD:-*** [**How to upload Multiple Files in Blob storage in DotNetCore**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453074/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-blob-storage-in-dotnetcore) as suggested by @[***Gaurav Mantri***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri)
- ***BLOG:-*** [***Upload Multiple Images In Azure Blob Storage***](https://satvasolutions.com/upload-multiple-images-in-azure-blob-storage/)